# Macbook Air overheating on firefox

Tags: firefox, power-management, battery, macbook, overheating

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my 2014 Macbook air .. when opening up firefox it starts to heat up a little  like from 49°c to 55-56°c .. and then when streaming video on youtube it just goes up to 78°-80°c in just 3-4 min . The battery life is also taking a big hit , because of this heating ..

have installed TLP and Powertop .. is thee any specific configeration that would help reduce the heating issue ?

anything else that would help the reduce the heating ..

Comment: Is your  system up to date? Maybe you can  try 15.10 . is it only Firefox? Maybe there is a bigger problem?

Comment: @user3892683 : yep everything is updated , i also tried 15.10 got the same result .. the problem seems to happen when doing something graphic intensive .. well i wouldn't call watching youtube to be a graphic intensive work .. but sadly i cant fix it ..

Answer (score 1):

Powertop is a good start. Your macbook air probably has a Sandy Bridge processor, and thus intel's turbo boost functionality, and Ubuntu would have that option turned on. Turning this off will save a massive amount of power and heat. Follow the guide [here](http://notepad2.blogspot.fr/2014/11/a-script-to-turn-off-intel-cpu-turbo.html) to turn it off.